# Does CartThrob support Stripe as a gateway in the UK?

Tags: cartthrob

The official Supported Payment Gateways page suggests Stripe can only be used in North America, but not in Europe:

http://cartthrob.com/docs/pages/supported_payment_gateways/index.html

I'm wondering if this page simply hasn't been updated since Stripe started supporting markets outside North America.

Can Stripe be successfully set up as a payment gateway with CartThrob for UK stores? And does it work with all the currencies supported by Stripe?

Answer (score 1):

Yes Stripe has a UK version and it works just fine with Cartthrob, see https://stripe.com/gb

Comment: Thanks for your reply Bluedreamer. I understand Stripe supports the UK and many other locations, but do you know that CartThrob specifically supports using Stripe from the UK? The official CartThrob page above suggests otherwise, and I would think it's possible that CartThrob is hard-coded with US-only in mind (since Stripe used to be US-only). Have you successfully used the UK version of Stripe with CT?

Comment: As far as I'm aware, the actual integration is on the Stripe side and not on the EE side. Your API credentials will set settings.

Comment: I've set up a test site using Cartthrob with Stripe GB and it's taking the test payments okay. So assume will be fine for the real thing. What do you think?

Comment: Stripe works find with Carthrob, I'm currently building a UK  EE+Cartthrob+Stripe site at the moment. As Steven said Stripe just does the payment processing behind the scenes, 'where' the processing takes place isn't really important.